# Change font size based on number of occurences in text

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my lame first attempt.  I would like to get a count of every unique word in a table.  Based on that count, I would like to change the size of the text.  I've tried to do this by adding a different class to every column on a table (so the first cell in the column of a table has a 'first' class, and the second cell in a table has a 'second' class in every column.  I'm trying to do this programatically so I don't have to brute force a regex for every word that might populate the table.  Any steerage in the right direction will be great :)

JS

```
$(function()
{
    var searchTerms = $('.thetable').text(); //get all search terms in table
    var words[] = text.split(''); //make them into an array
    for(var count =0, count < words.length; count++)
    {
    $('#results').append(words[i]);
    }
    if($('.first').length > 1).css({'font-size': 13 + 'px'}))
    else if($'.second').length > 1 && < 3).css({'font-size': 16 + 'px'}))
    else($('.third').length > 3).css({'font-size':18 + 'px'))
    }
});
```

HTML

```
<body>
<div id="results"></div>

<table style="width: 35%" cellspacing="1" class="thetable">
                <tr >
                                <td class="first">one</td>
                                <td class="second">three</td>
                                <td class="third">five </td>
                                <td class="fourth">six</td>
                                <td class="fifth">ten</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                                <td class="first">one</td>
                                <td class="second">three</td>
                                <td class="third">five</td>
                                <td class="fourth">seven</td>
                                <td class="fifth">ten</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                                <td class="first">one</td>
                                <td class="second">four</td>
                                <td class="third">five</td>
                                <td class="fourth">eight</td>
                                <td class="fifth">ten</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                                <td class="first">two</td>
                                <td class="second">four</td>
                                <td class="third">five</td>
                                <td class="fourth">nine</td>
                                <td class="fifth">ten</td>
                </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Comment: hey, thanks :).  this works for the count of numbers, but it doesn't seem to change the font size.  is this just something buggy with jsFiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var tds = $('table td');
var words = [];

tds.each(function() {
    var word = $(this).html();
    var num = $('td:contains(' + word.toLowerCase().trim() + ')', 'table').length;

    if (num <=1) {
        $(this).css('font-size', '13px');
    } else if(num > 1 && num < 3) {
        $(this).css('font-size', '23px');
    } else if (num > 3) {
        $(this).css('font-size', '60px');
    }
});
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/XRpzp/1/

Comment: thanks for the help..do you know why the word 'one' is small text when it appears three times?

Comment: Logic error, There is a 3 count but I'm using length of array which is zero based. If you changed `num < 3` to `<=` then it will work. http://jsfiddle.net/XRpzp/2/

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use something like `$('table.thetable tr').find('td:first')` to get the first cells, for example? You don't have to go through the grunt work of tagging the classes explicitly. Or to be more explicit, `find('td:eq(2)')` and so on.

Comment: this is the type of advice that i was coming for :).  i knew that i didn't have to name all those classes like i did, i just wasn't sure of a better way.  i'm not quite sure how your solution would work...

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to reduce the array to a list of words and you'll probably want a count of each:

```
var words[] = text.split(''); //make them into an array
var o={}
for(var count =0, count < words.length; count++)
{
if(words[i] in o)o[words[i]]++; else o[words[i]]=1;
}
```

do you want to sort the list of words by count (most to least)?

```
var i, wordsByCount = [];
for(i in o)wordsByCount.push([o[i],i]);
worsByCount = wordsByCount.sort(sortFunc);

function sortFunc(a,b){return b[0]-a[0];}

for(var count =0, count < wordsByCount.length; count++)
{
$('#results').append(wordsByCount[i][1]);
}
```

or if you want to show the words and the number of occurances

```
for(var count =0, count < words.length; count++)
{
$('#results').append(wordsByCount[i][1] + " (" + wordsByCount[i][0] + ")");
}
```

Comment: It's just there as an option to display the count of each word.  If you only want to display the words, use the version above it.

Comment: i tried the code in the second block, and i couldn't get it to work.  did you test it or am i just a dummy? :)

Comment: ok... I read your post a bit too quickly and assumed you were parsing the value of a textarea.  I see what you're doing now.  I'll post another answer in a little bit.

Comment: `$(function()
{
    var tds = $('.thetable td');
    var words = {};
    tds.each(function(){var s=$(this).html();if(s in words)words[s]++;else words[s]=1;});
    tds.each(function(){var i=words[$(this).html()];$(this).css("font-size", i==1?13:i==2?23:60 + "px");});
});`